# Minimal number of hyperplanes needed to separate sets of points from one other set

Tags: linear-programming, computational-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $\mathbb{R}^d$ be our space. We have a single good set of points $g$, and a collection of bad sets of points $B$.

We assume that for all $b \in B$ the convex hulls of $g$ and $b$ are disjoint. This means that there exist a hyperplane separating $g$ and $b$ (which we can find  in poly time with linear programming). We could repeatedly cut our space, eliminating one $b$ at a time, and be left with a subspace that only contains $g$ from our initial sets - this is what we want.

But we can do (a lot) better - we could separate multiple $b \in B$ from $g$ simultaneously with a single hyperplane. Is there an efficient algorithm that finds the minimal number of hyperplanes needed (and the partition of $B$ into groups you eliminate simultaneously)?

Comment: Does your proposed reduction to clique cover actually work?  What if you have, say,  in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $g$ containing only the origin and $B$ containing three sets, each with a single point on the unit circle, where the three single points are the vertices of a triangle that has the origin in its interior.  Then the resulting graph is a 3-clique (because every two of the three points is separable from the origin by a line), so the graph has a clique cover of size 1, but there is no single line that separates all three points from the origin.

Comment: @NealYoung Good point! I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is NP-complete, even in the following two highly restricted cases:

- The dimension $d$ is part of the input, and the question is whether you can separate set $B$ from set $G$ by $k=2$ hyperplanes.
- The dimension is $d=2$ (and the number $k$ of separating hyperplanes is part of the input).

This has been proved in:

> Nimrod Megiddo
>   On the Complexity of Polyhedral Separability
>   Discrete and Computational Geometry 3, pp 325-337, (1988).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Polyhedral separability was the keyword I was looking for.

Comment: Actually, my problem is harder because I wish to eliminate entire sets of points with a single hyperplane rather than individual points. This is because I'm actually interested in eliminating convex regions. If you were to eliminate single points at a time you could get errors like this: https://i.imgur.com/syw2ghb.png. Nevertheless your answer still applies because my problem is strictly harder and reduces by setting the cardinality of each set to $1$.